# Finger positions

Tags: midi, musicxml

I am writing an algorithm to calculate piano fingering. I want to add this number (1-5) for each note to a musicXML sheet and I did that by using the fingering property. Yet, the text is placed on the notes themselves in musescore instead of below or next to them. Do I need to use a different property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I was not putting any offset.  Musescore handles is very nice.

Comment: Can you give the complete xml block for fingering node ?

Answer (score 2):

The <fingering> element is indeed the correct one to use. You might try to use a different MusicXML reader such as Finale NotePad or one of the many other programs listed at http://www.musicxml.com/software and see if you get better results. MusicXML allows both positioning hints via the placement, relative-x, and relative-y attributes, as well as absolute positioning via the default-x and default-y attributes. However these are not consistently well supported for technical elements in the different MusicXML readers.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue with fingering annotations appearing on top of notes in MuseScore. I found a MuseScore plugin called 'Fingering Positioner' (download [here](https://musescore.org/en/project/fingering-positioner)) that was able to fix this pretty nicely.